# gdalwarp does not use lanczos resampling on image with alpha channel

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, resampling

I want to warp Geotiff image of shaded relief (RGBA) in projection EPSG:8353 to the projection EPSG:3857 to use it in Mapnik web tiled map. I want to use lanczos resampling, but the result image looks "jagged", like nearest resampling has been used. I am using this command:

```
gdalwarp \
  -of GTiff -overwrite -r lanczos  \
  -tr 1.194328566968441 1.194328566968441 -tap \
  -t_srs EPSG:3857 shading-sjtsk.tif shading-web.tif
```

The target resolution in georeferenced units is set to be the same as zoom level 17 in web mercator projection of tiled map.

Please could you advise me, why the lanczos resampling is not used? I tried also other methods (like cubic), but image always seems to be indistinguishable from nearest.

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Output image:

[image: Output image]

[Original tif images are shared here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FbZEkqIQTrfageZ6AguEB_4dqKJ8mSaq?usp=sharing).

Comment: Do you zoom in so much that the image is shown on screen at about native resolution (one raster pixel - on screen pixel)? Otherwise the viewer must also resample the image and it may hide the differences between the resampling methods of gdalwarp.

Comment: The image was displayed at 1:1 zoom with correct projection set in QGis.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with alpha band, which was not warped correctly. We need to prevent the alpha band of the source image to be considered as such with [`-nosrcalpha`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-nosrcalpha) parameter. Then it will be warped as regular band. Following command yields nice smooth image:

```
gdalwarp \
  -of GTiff -overwrite -r lanczos -nosrcalpha \
  -tr 1.194328566968441 1.194328566968441 -tap \
  -t_srs EPSG:3857 shading-sjtsk.tif shading-web.tif
```

Result image:

[image: Result image with lanczos resampling]

Comment: The source image has both alpha channel and nodata value `Band 1 Block=303x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=255
Band 2 Block=303x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=255
Band 3 Block=303x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=255
Band 4 Block=303x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=255`. Thus nodata is set two times. I am not sure if it is valid but at least it is uncommon. How the source image is created?

Comment: I made a test with GDAL 3.2 by unsetting nodata with gdal_edit. The result with your original command does not look good still. Would you mind to write a mail into gdal-dev because this feels like a bug? You could also edit the title of your question to describe the issue better.

Comment: Thank you for ideas, I changed the title, hopefully it is more clear now. The image is result of stacking separate channels with gdalbuildvrt and gdal_translate and is transparent in flat areas, because it is used as hill shading overlay. I think this warping behavior is not a bug, but the intended behavior as [described in gdalwarp documentation here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-nosrcalpha). But why the alpha band is handled differently in gdalwarp by default, I don't know...

Comment: Do separate channels mean that the stack is really 4-band image and RGB+alpha is wrong interpretation? It would be interesting to know more about the source images and exact gdalbuildvrt and gdal_translate commands that you used.

Comment: No, the image is meant to be RGBA, the color interpretation in source is correct. The script that generated the shading is [here](https://github.com/FreemapSlovakia/freemap-mapnik/blob/82c73a89a6ad7e6a319f5d673199a185f4a54ed1/shading/Makefile#L102), I'm using just different projection. I'm not the author, just using this shading technique.

Comment: The shading technique first creates shading in different directions and then generates separate RGB channels to colorize the result from different directions. See description [here](https://openstreetmap.cz/sotm-cz/2019/sotm2019-zdila-freemap-x.pdf#page=11)

Comment: The statistics of 4th band are `Band 4 Block=303x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=179.000, Mean=29.856, StdDev=22.227 NoData Value=255`. Looks like true alpha like it is for Photoshop etc. so that it is really meant to adjust the transparency, while most often in GIS imagery alpha is used just as binary mask with values of 0 or 255 to take care of the nodata areas. It feels like using 4th band as data band instead of alpha band is correct for your use case and GDAL. Zero values in alpha-as-nodata-mask drops out pixels from resampling also from the first three bands.